# An attempt at copying specific files to specific folders

Tags: linux, bash

This script copies all the files to all the folders. But I am struggling to construct a condition statement that will specify to which folder each file is copied to. I've tried the if statement but no copy is made at all.

The reason I use parameter expansion is because the file names are like, Long_John_Silver, Miss_Havisham and Master_Pip and the folder names are like Long, Miss and Master. So essentially I'm trying to copy the files to their respective folders e.g. Master_Pip.fna.gz into the folder named Master. And so what I've tried to do is to capture the first word of the file name and somehow use that as a reference.

```
for fldr in /home/scripts/playground/genomes_2/* ; do
    find . -name *fna.gz | while read f ; do
        basenm=${fldr##*/} ; f_name=${basenm%%_*} ; 
        cp -r $f /home/scripts/playground/port/$f_name/ ;
    done
done
```

This is my script with the if statement, but this script copies nothing at all.

```
for fldr in /home/scripts/playground/genomes_2/* ; do
    find . -name *fna.gz | while read f ; do
        basenm=${fldr##*/} ; f_name=${basenm%%_*} ; 
        if [ "$f_name" == /home/scripts/playground/port/"$f_name" ] ; then
            cp -r $f /home/scripts/playground/port/"$f_name"/ ;
        else
            continue    
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: how can `"$f_name"` could possibly equal to itself + another string ??? You might wanna test if the file already  exists  it the specific folder, fi so, use `if -f $myPathAndFile`

Comment: `"f_name"` is reference point. It extracts from the file name like so - "James_Bond" into "James".
I am doing this because all my files have multiple underscores but the beginning of the file is the name of a folder in a distant location i.e there is a folder called "James" somewhere. And there are 100s of these which is why I'm trying to automate this.

Comment: I understand this but ... `if [ "$f_name" == /home/scripts/playground/port/"$f_name" ]` ... i don't get how this can possibly work. It's like saying `x = 10 + x`

Comment: Yeah I agree it was a crucial mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I was copying all the files into all the folders based on the type of file i.e. .fna.gz, so I specified what type of fna.gz file I want to be read and then copied. There is no need for an if statement since the specificity is implied through the parameter expansion. It now works perfectly.

```
for fldr in /home/scripts/playground/genomes_2/* ; do

basenm=${fldr##*/} ; f_name=${basenm%%_*} ; 

find . -name $f_name*fna.gz | while read f ; do

    cp -r $f /home/scripts/playground/port/$f_name/ ;



done

done
```

Answer (score 1):

1.
Change this code

```
basenm=${fldr##*/};
```

to this one

```
basenm=${f##*/} ;
```

and remove -r switch from copy command

```
cp $f /home/scripts/playground/port/"$f_name"
```

Maybe you have some jumbled source paths like this /home/scripts/playground/genomes_2/Long_John_Silver/Master_Pip.fna.gz. So, when you're extracting f_name from folder name `fldr` you get 'Long'. Then you copy Master_Pip.fna.gz to the ..../Long folder.
2.

> "$f_name" == /home/scripts/playground/port/"$f_name"

they are not equal, and they won't.

Basically, your first script is good. Condition is redundant because you do it implicitly by parameter expansion.

I would only add directory creation command before copying. So you'll always have a directory to copy to in case new person appears in source directory, Shorty_Pete for example.

```
mkdir -p /home/scripts/playground/port/"$f_name"
cp ...
```

Comment: I have already created folders which don't exist in a previous step of the same script, I've only posted this part of the script.
Even still, if I remove the if statement, which I have tested, it copies all files into all folders and so the implicit specificity by parameter expansion actually doesn't seem to work.

Comment: OK. What are the names of subdirectories in the /home/scripts/playground/genomes_2  ? The only discrepancy I see that you extract f_name not from filename `$f` but from `$fldr` name.

Comment: Yeah that's a significant point actually, that I took into account in my solution.